# Android delete SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I have a problem with SharedPreferences in Android.
In my application, when I run the logout, I need to delete all SharedPreferences that I saved, because, on start the app verify if there are some SharedPreferences, if there are I have to login again, to do this use this code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
```

but, when I start the app again and check the presence of SharedPreferences with this code

```
String token = UserDefaultHelper.getStringPreferences(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.sharedPreferences_auth_token), "");
```

the String token has the same value that has before the logout,
someone can explain where's the error?

Comment: Try sharedPreferences.edit().remove("KeyName").commit();

Comment: Are you sure it returns the same value? I think your code is right...could you post your UserDefaultHelper class ?

Comment: @MartaTenés I have post the class in the answer
MicheleLacorte I need to remove all SharedPreferences, not only one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I post you and example, please try this code. It should works:

```
// Declare your shared preference file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "MyPrefs";
```

For deleting all the preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

For reading:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
String prefString = sharedPrefs.getString(key, "");
```

For writing:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.putString(key, "someValue");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have deleted all the files present in the default shared preferences folder(shared_prefs) and then cleared all the saved preferences. This will delete all your shared preferences data and does not store any further data at logout.

```
public void deletesharedpref(Context context) {

        File sharedPreferenceFile = new File("/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/shared_prefs/");
        File[] listFiles = sharedPreferenceFile.listFiles();
        for (File file : listFiles) {
            file.delete();
        }
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = sharedPref.edit().clear();
        editor.commit();
}
```

I have to store the first time Install boolean value as well. so after the above code I added some more lines:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = preferences.edit();
        prefsEditor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
        prefsEditor.commit();
```

By using this code you can easily clear all your shared preferences and start fresh with all new data. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

here's my UserDefaultHelper class

```
package com.example.ivan.posteggiaTI.helper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import com.example.ivan.posteggiaTI.AddParkingActivity;
/**
* Created by Ivan on 13/07/2015.
*/
public class UserDefaultHelper {


private static String name = "posteggiaTI_shared_preferences";

public static void setIntPreferences(Context context, String key, int value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static int getIntPreferences(Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void setStringPreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);//context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static String getStringPreferences(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);//context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void setBoolPreferences(Context context, String key, Boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public static boolean getBoolPreferences(Context context, String key, boolean defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
}

public static void setDoublePreferences(Context context, String key, double value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value));
    editor.commit();
}

public static double getDoublePreferences(Context context, String key, double doubleValue){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(sharedPreferences.getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(doubleValue)));
}

public static void removeAllSharedPreferences(Context context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}}
```

Comment: Are you sure the vale of the string R.string.sharedPreferences_auth_token is the same as "posteggiaTI_shared_preferences" ?

Comment: @MartaTenés isn't the same, R.string.sharedPreferences_auth_token is a key name of a pair key-value.
I use that code because I need to delete all the pair kay-value in the file path/posteggiaTI_shared_preferences, if I use like name R.string.sharedPreferences_auth_token I delete only the corresponding key-value pair, or not?

Comment: Ok, I think your problem is that you write and read in different files. Note that when you write you are writing to the file name "posteggiaTI_shared_preferences" and when you read you are using this instruction "usePreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences" which is a default file, not the file you created. I will post you some code and try this please.